# Run a bash script on boot of ubuntu server which does a constant loop

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, boot

I am in the middle of create a local FTP server and I need this script to run when the machine boots up:

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ 1 ];
do
chmod 2777 /home/ftp/folder;
chmod -R 777 /home/ftp/folder;
sleep 60;
done
```

Which is the best way to go about this?

I have tried to put it in the rc.local file but this doesn't allow the server to boot properly at all, also this script needs to be ran as sudo, if that will make a difference within the the script is ran.

Any help or ideas would be appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure about the "chmod -R 777".. this makes all files executable too. I'm paranoid, I don't want some description of "hey don't do: rm -rf /" turned into a script by being executable :)

Comment: I understand that but for what I'm creating it needs to be executable. The server can only be accessed internally and each account is assigned to individuals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whats about using a cronjob?

put

```
#!/bin/bash
chmod 2777 /home/ftp/folder
chmod -R 777 /home/ftp/folder
```

into a script file and invoke it every minute:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

and invoke with following:

```
* * * * * /path/to/script.sh
```

[further information - ubuntu wiki](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Cron)

Answer (score 0):

- Remove the loop from your script
- Place the script into some reasonable directory (e.g. `/usr/local/sbin/`)
- Place a cron job description into /etc/cron.d/ , e.g.

`* * * * * myuser /usr/local/sbin/myscript`

This will make your script run every minute. Then, to be completely on the safe side, you'd need to add some way to ensure that only once instance is running (i.e. to not run if another instance takes more than a minute to finish). This is usually done via lock files.